# Ресурс не найден. В чём причина?

Tags: javascript, xml, route

Суть в том, что есть страница, на которой загружена карта, на карте есть точка, которая показывает текущую локацию пользователя. Необходимо наложить на данную карту маршрут из gpx-файла, в котором записаны его координаты. С одной стороны, как мне кажется, код более-менее правильный, но в консоли выводит ошибку - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED route.gpx:1 и, соответственно маршрута на карте нет. В чём может быть проблема? поправка - файл gpx находится там же, где и файл со скриптом.

```js
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'route.gpx',
        format: new ol.format.GPX(),
    })
});
map.addLayer(vector);
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь к файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была связана с тем, что в необходимом GPX файле были найдены ошибки в описании того, что это есть GPX файл, а не какой-либо XML-подобный.